# How to connect microphone to computer? Pre-amp with galvanic isolation

Tags: microphone, condenser-microphone

I have audio card with Hi-Fi input, but it is strictly stereo TRS (not balanced).

I have condenser microphone with balanced TRS output.

I found that mic output is very low, and I receive too much noize from its shield.

I need to connect microphone with galvanic isolation to drop all noize, so it should have absolutly clean zero level. I know it is capable of at least 50 dB of SNR, but now only 15 dB.

I opened mic, everything looks good, it is supplied with small (passive) powering scheme inside, involving few small transistors.

Ok, I have done some research and came to conclusion, I just used condenser mic without any power supply (hehe).

After some considerations I came up with this scheme.
Am I right to not connect shield from everything to GROUND/MIC_IN of sound card?
I will probably use batteries to achieve perfect noize-free environment.
Any recommendations on using capacitors before amplifier?

[image]

Comment: Can your condenser mic take a battery, or does it rely solely on phantom power?

Comment: Looks like only phantom power, limited by 50 volts. Inside two capacitors of 47+22 microF of 50v max.

Comment: Connecting capacitors are 1 microF. Scheme looks decent for that low class balanced mics.

Comment: PS3: Condensor mics don't work without power. He-he.

Comment: @sanaris: You don't have to screengrab the CircuitLab schematic. Just save and it will auto-embed in your post and you (or we) can edit it later.

Comment: @sanaris: (1) There is something wrong with your circuit trace. Both of the electret capsule terminals are pulled to 48 V so there is no voltage across them. That can't give any output. One must go to ground. (2) Is there a 48 V battery in the microphone? Can we have a photo?

Comment: There is another circuit inside mic, so it is not "electret" output. It is "cold and hot" corresponding to bowing of electret inside/outside. And they should be uplifted to ~40 volts to work with mic, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given any datasheet link for the microphone so this is all a guess.

- The mic is low-Z - probably 600 Ω output.
- Your amp is hi-Z - probably > 10 kΩ input.

The simplest solution is a microphone transformer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffJuuM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Microphone "unbalancer" and impedance matching.*

A really good transformer is expensive and some active circuits may give better frequency response for the same money. The big advantage with the transformer solution is that no power is required.

[image]

*Figure 2. A typical microphone impedance matching transformer. No messing!*

---

It now appears that the microphone is a 48 V electret. This usually means that it is phantom powered.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOlv17.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Rough schema for a balanced line microphone to unbalanced hi-Z input.*

The usual scheme for a balanced line, phantom-powered microphone is as shown in Figure 3.

- Power is fed through the centre-tap of the unbalancing transformer at the amplifier end. Current splits both ways through the transformer (cancelling out each other's magnetising so the core doesn't saturate) and travels along both signal lines to the mic. The screen is the 48 V return.
- At the mic the reverse is done and the 48 V current is extracted from the centre-tap. This is filtered and regulated (neither shown) to power the signal amplifier and provide the electret bias (not shown).
- The electret capsule will have a high output impedance. The amplifier will buffer this and drive the hi-Z input to the transformer - typically 10 kΩ.
- The transformer steps down the signal and decreases the impedance to 200 - 600 Ω.
- At the receiving end the signal is unbalanced, the signal stepped up and, as a result, the impedance raised to 10 kΩ again.

Comment: Basically I have some "amplification-like" scheme inside microphone body. Should I put phantom supply right between "cold" and "ground" output of microphone? How much volts? I have 3.7V standart battery I can insert it there to power inner amp of microphone, right?

Comment: You need to provide a link to the datasheet for the microphone. How could anyone guess what the right voltage is for your microphone?

Comment: @sanaris: See the update. Does this represent what's going on in your mic?

Comment: Can I disconnect wire below XFMR3 connecting common ground? I don't have "true" ground to get to right now.

Comment: Wire below what? Why? Use schematic.

Comment: Any recommendations about number of rounds I should use for XFMR3?

Comment: Sorry, @sanaris, but this question is turning into a senseless rambling. You don't answer the questions asked in the comments and instead start asking unrelated questions such as "rounds for XMFR3". I have to leave this question now. Bye.